# find command delete option failed to remove folders

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to all subdirectories and its contents with the name "bin". I've used the find command with option -delete to perform the delete and it has worked to some degree (JFX folders begin at 01 and I've managed to delete "bin" folders up to JFX13). However, not all "bin" folders and its contents are deleted, which makes me very puzzled.

I would appreciate if anyone can figure out what I'm not doing correctly.

Here's how it looks right now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`man` page of `find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), `-delete` is for deleting files also folders but *only* if there are no files inside. So instead of first deleting the files and then the folders again, I would suggest to use `-exec` with `rm -rf` to clean up altogether in one-shot.

```
find . -name "bin" -type d -exec rm -rf "{}" +
```

The actual information from te `man find` page,

```
-delete
       Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal
       failed, an error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's
       exit status will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use
       of -delete automatically turns on the `-depth' option.
```

This calls `rm -rf` on the all the folders returned from `find` command in one-shot rather than involing one `rm` command for every folder found.

Note:- Use `rm -rf` carefully. Run this only if you are ***absolutely*** sure of the folders you want to delete, avoid running it otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure? It deletes only files. I just tried to delete directory/folder. It successfully deleted directory. But condition is that file should not contains any files

Comment: Ok I should agree as man page is saying that. But I just deleted empty directory using -delete option and it's working :)

Comment: @It will work if the folders contents are empty ( hope you are not confusing it here), but why not when folders contain files. So instead of this two fold approach better use `find` with `rm -rf` which cleans up all.

Comment: Totally agree with your answer of using `rm -rf` with `find` as delete option not working with non empty directory. btw `xargs rm -rf` should also work. :)